# QT send signal to another QT application?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I've got three applications:

> - ApplicationLauncher.exe
> - Updater.exe
> - MyApplication.exe

I want to use the `ApplicationLauncher.exe` to launch the `Updater.exe` and when the `Updater.exe` is finished updating it should send a signal to `ApplicationLauncher.exe` which then should launch `MyApplication.exe`

This reason for this is because `Updater.exe` requires admin rights to update, so I want to keep `ApplicationLauncher.exe` running while the updater is doing its work and then use `ApplicationLauncher.exe` to launch `MyApplication.exe`

To get this to work I need a way for `ApplicationLauncher.exe` to know when `Updater.exe` is done.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to spawn a process, and wait until it is finished. There is no data communicated, so no real IPC.

Because the updater requires elevated privileges, you can not use QProcess. We are on windows, and you need to fall back to the win32 API.

```
QDir exePath(QCoreApplication::instance()->applicationDirPath());
QString exeFileName = exePath.absoluteFilePath("update.exe");
QByteArray exeFileNameAnsi = exeFileName.toAscii();

    // we must use ShellExecuteEx because we need admin privileges on update
    // the standard QProcess functions do not provide this.
    SHELLEXECUTEINFOA lpExecInfo;
    lpExecInfo.cbSize  = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    lpExecInfo.lpFile = exeFileNameAnsi.constData();
    lpExecInfo.fMask=SEE_MASK_DOENVSUBST|SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    lpExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
    lpExecInfo.lpVerb = "open";
    lpExecInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
    lpExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
    lpExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW ;
    lpExecInfo.hInstApp = (HINSTANCE)SE_ERR_DDEFAIL;
    if( ShellExecuteExA(&lpExecInfo) && lpExecInfo.hProcess != NULL) {
        DWORD retval;
        DWORD waitresult;
        do {

            waitresult = WaitForSingleObject(lpExecInfo.hProcess, 10);
        } while (waitresult == WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        GetExitCodeProcess(lpExecInfo.hProcess, &retval);
        CloseHandle(lpExecInfo.hProcess);

        if(retval == 0) {
            // launched and finished without errors
        }
    } else {
       // failed to launch
    }
```

I think you may also need to link to shell32.lib in your PRO file, not sure.

```
LIBS += -lshell32
```

Comment: How would an example of starting and seeing when it finished look? Not sure I completely follow

Comment: QProcess seems to fail to start the Updater.exe cause it needs admin privileges

Comment: Added that to the .pro of the `Updater.exe` but still does not open

Comment: I forgot... you can't use QProcess in this case.

Comment: Anything to use instead of `toAscii()`? Does not seem to be supported

Comment: This works exactly the way I wanted it to! Thanks for saving me a lot of hours!!

Comment: One thing; how can I get the launcher to exit after retval == 0? I've tried: `QApplication::quit();` but launcher stays open

Comment: That depends. Do you have a standard main() function where you enter an event loop? Ending in return app.exec() or similar?

Comment: My main: ` QApplication a(argc, argv); MainWindow w; w.show(); return a.exec();`

Comment: Hmmm.. can't really tell whats wrong then. Check that quit is really executed (debug breakpoint) and that you return to the Qt eventloop.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified that you are running under Windows, I think the simplest is to use the windows messaging system. A description of those: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Now, in the Qt application you will need to work with QWidget's winEvent: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#winEvent.

The page http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtwinmigrate/winmigrate-win32-in-qt-example.html has a good example on how to make a Windows aware Qt application.

However if you really want only to check that an application finished, then just start the "Updater.exe" via the `runas` command (http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19060) to run as an Administrator then wait for it to finish (QProcess::waitForFinished (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#waitForFinished))